# concourse lite yml digest error while creating BOSH env

Tags: concourse

I have downloaded BOSH and trying to run the `councourse-lite.yml` which I got from

`wget https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/download/v3.9.0/concourse-lite.yml`

and executing `bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml`

Right now I am getting the digest mismatch error like below while downloading the concourse-3.9.0-3541.2.tgz

`Failed to download from 'https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/download/v3.9.0/concourse-3.9.0-3541.2.tgz':
  Verifying digest for downloaded file:
    Expected stream to have digest '6cc893c34ee4a504d59a06b2df3413d6e5a68e10' but was '43c8ef28fb100441efd0fb80244f979c7859f983'`

Is this something we have to fix in the concourse-lite.yml file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error when installing singleVM while ago, so i tried to use the v3.8.0 of concourse-lite.yml

```
wget https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/download/v3.8.0/concourse-lite.yml
```

and then `bosh create-env concourse-lite.yml` worked thru all setup.

btw i was using relatively fresh copy of ubuntu 16.04 and during setup, it complained ruby was not in $PATH, so i had to install it and then re-run the bosh create-env again.

Comment: I have installed ruby2.5 and its progressing now with 3.8. However, it is giving error while uploading stemcell. `VBoxManage: executable file not found in $PATH","ok_to_retry":false} Exit code 1`

Comment: i think i had virtualbox installed on my ubuntu while ago and looks like the SingleVM setup seemed to use it. so try install virtualbox prior to bosh create-env (and after setup, if u opens virtualbox vm manager, there're few VMs would be added and running...)